# Mockito for REST + DAO objects

Tags: java, rest, junit, mockito

This is my mock code for testing end to end:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class testRest extends Jersey Test{
DAOFactory mockDAOfactory;
RPRestrictionReasonDAO fakeDao;

@Before
public void init() {
    mockDAOfactory = mock(DAOFactory.class);
    fakeDao = mock(RPRestrictionReasonDAO.class);
}
@Test
public void testServiceWorks() throws Exception {
//Assuming I hav already initialized restrictReasons with a dummy value
when(fakeDao.findAll()).thenReturn(restrictReasons);
when(mockDAOfactory.getRPRestrictionReasonDAO()).thenReturn(fakeDao);
String response = client().resource("http://localhost:9998/")
            .path("EmployerDetails/PossibleRestrictions")
            .get(String.class);
    System.out.println("Response is " + response.toString());
}
}
```

Whenever I do this, I always get the ACTUAL results in my DB rather than the restrictReasons. I've tried all blogs but nothing seems to help. How I get around this? lemme know If I need to post more code.

Note: I have implemented the methods while extending Jersey Test with Grizzly container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell from your code, you are creating the mocks but not actually using the mocks in your client / server implementation.

For a mock to work, it needs to be used by the underlying implementation, not just created in your test class.  In this case, assuming your test is running in the same JVM as the server you are testing against, you need to inject your created mocks into the classes that rely on them.

The other answer by @inkalimeva is attempting to address this issue for you by injecting the mocks into your DAO factory.  You may be able to fix the error you are experiencing with that answer by changing the DAOFactory declaration to be the concrete class used instead of the abstract one.

E.g.

```
@InjectMocks
DAOFactoryImpl mockFactory;
```

Assuming DAOFactoryImpl is your concrete factory class.

Comment: Thanks. My rest has the following autowired. 
    private DAOFactory daoFactory;
    private HibernateDAOFactoryKepler hibernateDAOFactoryKepler;
    private ApplicationContext appcontext;
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;
 and all this is done in the REST class - employeeREST. Do I inject EmployeeREST?

Comment: @chipmunk I assume you want to test EmployeeRest so you cannot inject it, but you need to inject into it.  Not sure of your exact setup or code, but one easy workaround here may be to add a setter to your rest class to set the DAOFactory and then explicitly set it to be the mock after the mock is created.  The problem here being that it will only work for that one class then which is why InjectMock exists to handle it on a more comprehensive basis.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, with injecion of mocks using annotations.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class testRest extends Jersey Test {
    @InjectMocks
    DAOFactory mockDAOfactory;
    @Mock
    RPRestrictionReasonDAO fakeDao;

    @Before
    public void init() 
        //Do nothing
        //mockDAOfactory = mock(DAOFactory.class);
        //fakeDao = mock(RPRestrictionReasonDAO.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testServiceWorks() throws Exception {
        //Assuming I hav already initialized restrictReasons with a dummy value
        when(fakeDao.findAll()).thenReturn(restrictReasons);
        when(mockDAOfactory.getRPRestrictionReasonDAO()).thenReturn(fakeDao);
        String response = client().resource("http://localhost:9998/")
                .path("EmployerDetails/PossibleRestrictions")
                .get(String.class);
        System.out.println("Response is " + response.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, tried that but I get this: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field named 'mockDAOfactory'.
You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.
However, I failed because: the type 'DAOFactory is an abstract class.

Comment: I am not sure here but can you try changing the type of mockDAOfactory to a concrete implementation such as HibernateDAOFactoryKepler and as @increment1 points out the mocks are not used in your test. Maybe you should be mocking the service?

Comment: won't work anyway since the test is calling a server and the mocking is done locally. See answer from increment1.